# MySQL Max function mixing rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Seems like i'm having fundamental problems using MAX - it's mixing the contents of rows, i think.

There is a View:

```
id   rev   state
1    100   pass
1    99    fail
1    98    fail
```

Result should be:

```
id   rev   state
1    100   **pass**
```

but i get this on the query below

```
id   rev   state
1    100   **fail**

SELECT r.id, r.state, MAX(r.revision)
FROM VIEW_data r
WHERE r.id=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `GROUP BY` clause with the aggregate `MAX()`. MySQL permits you to omit it (where other RDBMS would report errors) but with indeterminate results, which you are seeing.  This can be handled by joining against a subquery which returns the grouped `rev` per `id`.

```
SELECT 
  r.id,
  r.state,
  maxrev.rev
FROM
  VIEW_data r
  /* INNER JOIN against subquery which returns MAX(rev) per id only */
  JOIN (
    SELECT id, MAX(rev) AS rev
    FROM VIEW_data GROUP BY id
  /* JOIN is on both id and rev to pull the correct value for state */
  ) maxrev  ON r.id = maxrev.id AND r.rev = maxrev.rev
WHERE r.id = 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f651/8

The above will return the max `rev` value for any `id`. If you are *certain* you only need the one row as filtered by the `WHERE` clause rather than the `MAX()` per group, look at the other answer which makes use of `ORDER BY` & `LIMIT`.

Comment: this does work amazingly.  i still do not understand why the query i had would mix the contents of rows. is it just a mysql thing?

Comment: @glutz It is a MySQL thing, maybe SQLite too.  If you tried your original query on SQL Server for example, you would have gotten errs like _r.id is invalid in the SELECT list because it is not contained in GROUP BY_.  Columns in the `SELECT` should be in the `GROUP BY`- MySQL's default behavior doesn't require it, and instead choose an arbitrary value to fill in the group because it can't choose a row unambiguously.  People who learn aggregate functions on MySQL often have to re-learn them the "right way" when beginning to work with Oracle, MSSQL, Postgres, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT r.id, r.state, r.revision
FROM VIEW_data r
WHERE r.id = 1
ORDER BY r.revision DESC
LIMIT 0,1
```