# MySQL MAX() function returns wrong associated value

Tags: mysql

I've tried various queries and read different answers to this and nothing seems to give EXACTLY what I'm looking for. Advice is appreciated.

I have a table with items, dates and quantities. For each item, I need the latest date and associated quantity. The table looks like this:

```
item   date         qty
1234   2014-12-22   300
1234   2015-02-13   500
```

After running this query:

```
SELECT item, MAX(date), qty
FROM table
GROUP BY item
```

I get this:

```
item   date         qty
1234   2015-02-13   300
```

Instead of a `qty` of `500`. I've tried a couple of different solutions including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995786/mysql-max-function-mixing-rows) and  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537223/mysql-control-which-row-is-returned-by-a-group-by?lq=1). The first one gave all the records with `NULL` in `date`. The second one seems to work, until I try to do `SUM(qty)` (there can be multiple `qty` for an `item` on any given `date`). Since this solution sorts by `date` descending, and does not actually cut out any data, it doesn't help in this scenario.

Why does my original query not work? Any other ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it does.  You need a `join` to get what you want:

```
select t.*
from table t join
     (select item, max(date) as maxd
      from table t
      group by item
     ) tmax
     on t.item = tmax.item and t.date = tmax.maxd;
```

Your query should fail because `qty` is not in the `group by`.  MySQL allows it, but any other database would return an error.

Comment: I think I had the wrong field somewhere - just redid it and it works! That's what you get for trying to work when you should be sleeping.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand how `max()` works. I want to see `qty` grouped by `itemnum`, how would grouping by `qty` help here?

Comment: @AldermanJaw . . . `max()` returns the maximum value of a column.  It does not return the row with the maximum value.

Answer (score 2):

Your query doesn't work because `mysql` just returns an arbitrary row when using `group by` like this.  In fact, most databases won't even run this.

There are a couple alternative options -- here's one joining the table back to itself:

```
SELECT t1.item, t1.date, t1.qty
FROM table t1 
    JOIN (select item, max(date) maxdate
          from table
          group by item) t2 ON t1.item = t2.item 
    and t1.date = t2.maxdate
```